# The picture is invisible until the user start's to typing in Angular Metronic theme

Tags: angular, image, typescript

In metronic theme I have a FormWizard with four tabs. On the second tab I load an image from my file system into an input field, and I try to save the whole form on the fourth tab. In case I missed to fill some fields and the backend gives error response, I click back to the second tab and my image is disappeared until I start to write anything into another input field beside of the image input. When I start typing the image becomes visible immediately.

In `app.module.ts` I have already set this: `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`

```html
<!--begin: Form Wizard Step 2-->
<div class="kt-wizard-v4__content" data-ktwizard-type="step-content">
  <div class="kt-section kt-section--first">
    <div class="kt-wizard-v4__form">
      <div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--bordered">
        <div class="kt-portlet__head">
          <div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
            <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">
               Galéria 
               <span class="required-field">*</span> 
               <i class="fa fa-info-circle kt-font-info"
                  data-toggle="kt-popover" title=""
                  data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"
                  data-original-title="Popover title">
               </i>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="kt-portlet__head-toolbar">
              <div class="kt-portlet__head-actions">
                <label for="file" title="Kép felviteléhez kattintson ide">
                   <input #file type="file" name="image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="file"
                        class="inputfile" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
                    <button href="#" (click)="file.click()" class="btn btn-success btn-pill btn-wide">
                        képfeltöltés
                    </button>
                </label>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```js
    onSelectFile(event) {
        let element: HTMLElement = 
                     document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLElement;
        element.click();
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file); // read file as data url

            reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
                this.addPicture(reader.result, file);
                this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

            };
        }
    }
```

[image]

There is no error message, only the image is invisible.

Comment: I would start by throwing a debugger inside of your `onSelectFile()` - my guess is that this function is getting called when you type in one of these other input boxes? If that's the case you could listen to the wizard navigation and when navigating to this step (step 2 by the looks of it) call the function to load the image in so that you don't need to type in the input.

Comment: The problem was formcontrol uploaded duplicated datas, i mean the controll uploaded the image and after that it uploaded the base64 version too. This cause nedless big network traffic. To solve this issue before the whole upload process i just removed the  base64 part of it.